# Migrating slots from Vue 2 to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I roughly followed [this article](https://dev.to/mandrewcito/vue-js-draggable-div-3mee) to make a component draggable:

```html
<template>
  <div ref="draggableContainer" class="draggable-container">
    <div class="draggable-header" @mousedown="dragMouseDown">
      <slot name="dragger"></slot>
    </div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

and then in my `Calculator.vue` component I have:

```html
<template>
  <Draggable class="calculator">
    <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" slot="dragger" value="" />

    <div class="calculator-keys">
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>

      <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
      <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
      <button type="button" value="9">9</button>

      <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
      <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
      <button type="button" value="6">6</button>

      <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
      <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
      <button type="button" value="3">3</button>

      <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
      <button type="button" class="decimal" value=".">.</button>
      <button type="button" class="all-clear" value="all-clear">AC</button>

      <button type="button" class="equal-sign operator" value="=">=</button>
    </div>
  </Draggable>
</template>
```

Both components use `slot` in different ways, in the `draggable-maker` as a tag, and in the calculator as an attribute. However, this is not Vue 3 compatible due to the use of `slot`s. Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: errormsg]

Can someone please suggest how I may fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `slot` attribute is deprecated and it's replaced by `v-slot:slotname` for named slots and you should use it as follows :

```html
  <Draggable class="calculator">
   <template v-slot:dragger>

   <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value="" />
    <div class="calculator-keys">
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>

      <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
      <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
      <button type="button" value="9">9</button>

      <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
      <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
      <button type="button" value="6">6</button>

      <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
      <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
      <button type="button" value="3">3</button>

      <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
      <button type="button" class="decimal" value=".">.</button>
      <button type="button" class="all-clear" value="all-clear">AC</button>

      <button type="button" class="equal-sign operator" value="=">=</button>
    </div>
</template>
  </Draggable>
```

don't forget to remove `slot="dragger"`  from `input` element, the syntax that you use is deprecated from the version 2.6.0 which will include the v3

Comment: Looks like it worked, thank you! Are you also suggesting to remove the wrapper `<template>` that's outside of `<Draggable>` (it's in my question's snippet but not in your response)?

Comment: no you couldn't it's the component wrapper used by vue.js